# i want see level db

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ethereumjs, leveldb

I am a beginner studying blockchain in Korea. Recently, I completed 100% synchronization of the goerli testnet using geth as my client. I want to visualize the chaindata/.sst files.

Also, I am curious about why Ethereum blockchain data is stored in NoSQL databases like LevelDB and RocksDB from a technical perspective.

Thank you in advance for providing a detailed response.